# How to fix “XPath Injection” in c# asp.net? Fortify issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, fortify

I got a “XPath Injection” issue from Fortify scan for below code,

```
                string username = string.Empty;
                string password = string.Empty;
                string officePrefix = "";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(securityNode.Prefix))
                {
                    officePrefix = securityNode.Prefix + ":";
                    ns.AddNamespace(securityNode.Prefix, securityNode.Namespace);
                }
                var regexPattern = 
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxx"];
                var regexItem = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.None);
                   if(regexItem.IsMatch(officePrefix ))
                     {
                    //wsse:UsernameToken
                    XmlNode usernameTokenNode = securityNode.SelectSingleNode(officePrefix + 
                   "UsernameTkn", ns);

                    username = usernameTokenNode.SelectSingleNode(officePrefix + "name", ns).InnerText;
                    password = usernameTokenNode.SelectSingleNode(officePrefix + "Pwd", ns).InnerText;
```

above code i am getting issue from (                    XmlNode usernameTokenNode = securityNode.SelectSingleNode(officePrefix +
"UsernameToken", ns);) this line of code. So, I tried to use regex and as you can see in the code. Even though the xpath injection issue still persists. Can any one kindly give a solution for the xpath injection issue.

Comment: Where are `securityNode` and `ns` declared? It seems you should use your own static prefix, rather than using the one inside the XML. The prefix alias you use in your own `NamespaceManager` is not related to the namespace alias in the actual XML

Comment: thanks for the reply but i am getting the issue in (officePrefix + "UsernameTkn").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to re-use the namespace alias from the actual XML. you can use your own. The only thing is that the actual namespace must be the same

```cs
string username = string.Empty;
string password = string.Empty;
const string officePrefix = "myPrefix";
bool hasPrefix = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityNode.Namespace);
if (hasPrefix)
{
    ns.AddNamespace(officePrefix, securityNode.Namespace);
}

XmlNode usernameTokenNode = securityNode.SelectSingleNode(hasPrefix ? officePrefix + ":UsernameTkn" : "UsernameTkn", ns);

username = usernameTokenNode.SelectSingleNode(hasPrefix ? officePrefix + ":name" : "name", ns).InnerText;
password = usernameTokenNode.SelectSingleNode(hasPrefix ? officePrefix + ":Pwd" : "Pwd", ns).InnerText;
```

I note that `XName` and `XNode` are newer and much easier to use, they are in the `System.Xml.Linq` library.